# Error: Could not find or load main class only on my system

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

My problem is quite specific, so I'm trying to be as presice as possible.
  I am working on a libgdx project together with friends using a git repository. We used the libgdx setup app to initially set up the project.  First I imported the gradle project into eclipse via file->import->gradle project->existing gradle project. This worked fine. The nested projects popped up in the explorer.  Now the first problem arised: When I ran the desktop project as java application I got the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class <classname>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <classname>`. I tested it on a different computer and there was no problem. Same on the computers of my friends. Since I did not find a suitable solution on the web that was working I uninstalled java, eclipse and even the java sdk. I deleted the folder .gradle as well. Afterwards I reinstalled the newest versions of java sdk, eclipse and java itself.  Then I tried importing the project again.. But when importing the gradle project the finish button didnt work anymore. So i updated the gradle version in eclipse marketplace. The finish button worked again but the nested projects didnt appear in the explorer. So i added them manually with 'open project from file system. Besides having multiple error warnings, because the imports for the libgdx libraries somehow dont work, I also still have the initial error when running... : `Error: Could not find or load main class <classname>
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <classname>`.
I might need to add: I am working on macOS and every pc the project works on is using windows.

Comment: Please provide **useful** information, for example the command you are running, and the file path, etc.

Comment: I am just clicking Run as->Java application. What filepath do you require?

Comment: Is your java is added to classpath? If yes, then your class which you are running is added to classpath?

Comment: Also provide the code along with the exception stack trace so that precise help could be given.

Comment: One missing information you gave implicitely is that you use Eclipse. On what file or folder did you click Run as->Java application? You need to use the desktop's launcher class, and you need to set the asset directory as the working directory.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error using IntelliJ. I am using `Run 'DesktopLauncher.main()'`. where do I find the classpath? @MrStahlfelge

Comment: See here [how to set up your IDE](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation/gettingstarted/Running%20and%20Debugging.html#running-desktop-project-in-intellij-android-studio).